# File not being load (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I have 3 files (`loader.sh`, `core/info.sh` and `main.sh`). Here's the contents of the files:
`main.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bash loader.sh

info "Test"
```

`loader.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in core/*.sh ; do
    source $i
done
```

`core/info.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RESET="\x1B[0m"
GREEN="\x1B[01;32m"

function info() {
    printf "(${GREEN}Info${RESET}): $1\n"
}
```

Logically, it should "load" my files but I get this error:

```
main.sh: line 5: info command not found
```

Which means there's a problem either in my `loader.sh` or `core/info.sh`

Comment: `bash loader.sh` will not "source" `loader.sh`. You are launching another shell, thus you don't get anything defined in your `main.sh`.

Comment: Just replace `bash loader.sh` with `source loader.sh` (otherwise loader.sh is loaded in a separate "subshell"…)

Comment: As @ErikMD says.

Comment: @ErikMD yes, thank you